# Same BSD socket API program works in Python but not in C++ or Rust

Tags: python, c++, c, sockets, rust

I've been trying to listen to multicast UDP messages from my Yeelight smart bulb. At a regular interval, the bulb broadcasts its presence on IP `239.255.255.250` port `1982`. Also, when sending a specific request ([found on page 5 - section 3.1](https://www.yeelight.com/download/Yeelight_Inter-Operation_Spec.pdf)) on the same IP and port, the bulb will respond.

Using sockets, I am trying to establish the communication. On two machines (macOS and Linux), the Python program shown below run at the REPL works, but the Rust code and C++ code also shown below (essentially doing the same thing) doesn't. The Rust program seems to successfully receive 0 bytes twice and then hangs waiting. In the C++ program, the `recv` function just hangs right away, never returning.

What could be the problem? Why can only Python successfully communicate?

```py
import socket as s
import struct

sock = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_DGRAM, s.IPPROTO_UDP)

sock.setsockopt(s.IPPROTO_IP, s.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, struct.pack("4sL", s.inet_aton("239.255.255.250"), s.INADDR_ANY))

sock.sendto("M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1982\r\nMAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST: wifi_bulb\r\n".encode('UTF-8'), ("239.255.255.250", 1982))

sock.recv(4096) # Message received successfully right away from first call
```

```rust
#[macro_use] extern crate log;
use socket2::{Socket, Domain, Type, Protocol, SockAddr};
use std::net::{SocketAddrV4, Ipv4Addr};

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let yeelight_ip = Ipv4Addr::new(239, 255,255, 250);
    let yeelight_port: u16 = 1982;

    let socket = Socket::new(
        Domain::ipv4(), 
        Type::dgram(), 
        Some(Protocol::udp())
    ).expect("Failed to create socket!");

    socket.join_multicast_v4(
        &yeelight_ip, 
        &Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED
    ).expect("Unable to join multicast broadcast!");

    let msg = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1982\r\nMAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST: wifi_bulb\r\n";
    match socket.send_to(
        msg.as_bytes(), 
        &SockAddr::from(
            SocketAddrV4::new(
                yeelight_ip, 
                yeelight_port
            )
        )
    ) {
        Ok(bytes_sent) => {
            // Some lines of debug printing
        },
        Err(_) => eprintln!("Error broadcasting request for identification!")

    loop {
        let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(1024 * 1024);
        let received_bytes = socket
            .recv(&mut buffer)
            .expect("Unable to receive message!");
        debug!("Received {} bytes", received_bytes);
    }
}
```

```cpp
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

const std::string msg = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1982\r\nMAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST: wifi_bulb\r\n";

int main() {
    auto yeelight_ip = in_addr();
    inet_aton("239.255.255.250", &yeelight_ip);

    unsigned int yeelight_port = 1982;

    auto sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    std::cerr << "Created socket!" << std::endl;

    auto mreq = ip_mreq();
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = yeelight_ip.s_addr;

    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error joining multicast!" << std::endl;
        exit(errno);
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Joined multicast!" << std::endl;
    }

    auto addr = sockaddr_in();
    addr.sin_port = yeelight_port;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) addr.sin_zero[i] = 0;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr = yeelight_ip;

    if (sendto(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.length(), 0, (sockaddr*)(&addr), sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error broadcasting request for identification!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << errno << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Sent broadcast request for idetification!" << std::endl;
    }

    while (true) {
        std::array<char, 1024 * 1024> buffer;
        auto bytes_read = recv(sock, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 0);
        if (bytes_read == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to receive message!" << std::endl;
            std::cerr << errno << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Read " << bytes_read << " bytes..." << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + bytes_read) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your Rust program receives in a loop: your Swift program receives once. They are not equivalent. You're ignoring the message length when you unwrap the received buffer in the Rust code.

Comment: I fail to see how those can be seen as issues. The fact that Python received instantly while Rust doesn't receive in a loop should be even more concerning. Also, what message length am I ignoring?

Comment: `String::from_utf8(buffer)` ignores the value of `received_bytes`. I fail to see how reading in a loop could *fail* to be an issue The loop can only iterate if you *did* receive something, and the failure to use the length properly is sufficient to account for your belief that you received 0 bytes.

Comment: If you look at the last debug!() call, I am printing the `received_bytes`, which is 0.

Comment: But you aren't making the `message` correctly.

Comment: That is irrelevant to my problem though, and the program doesn't panic in Rust and instead it prints that `received_bytes` is 0. I don't care how I'm building the message if there is no message to be built in the first place. You are nitpicking on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python program works as expected due to Python nicely implementing conversions behind the scenes.

The C(++) program didn't work because the endianness of the port was wrong. I forgot that I have to use `addr.sin_port = htons(yeelight_port);`.

As for the Rust program, I forgot that `with_capacity` only allocated the internal buffer, but the `Vec` is still empty. The solution, described [here](https://github.com/alexcrichton/socket2-rs/issues/89), is to call `buffer.resize(buffer.capacity(), 0);`.